# C# HttpClient asynchronously send data to cloud every 5 seconds

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to use`HttpClient` to send data to cloud every 5 seconds. I don't really care about responses (probably only log errors) and want to send it asynchronously so as not to block my main thread. The following function is what I used. It works fine when I try individual inputs, but stops working (can't send anything to cloud) as soon as I put in the 5-second loop

```
private static async Task SendToCloudAsync(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("some url");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
        {
            var path = string.Format("variabels/{0}/values.json", kvp.Key);
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, path);
            request.Content = new StringContent(kvp.Value);

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        }
    }
```

And then in a `System.Timers.Timer` triggered function I just call it like so

```
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Interval = 50000;
timer.SynchronizingObject = this
timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.someKindOfLoop);

private void someKindOfLoop(System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var dict = generateDict();
    var task = SendToCloudAsync(dict);
    // I also tried Task.Run(async () => { await sendToCloud(dict); });
}
```

Any suggestion where I have done wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "It stops working"?

Comment: in what way does it stop working?   You'll need to await it or something;  just calling it like you have there won't work.  How is the loop controlled?  Is this in a desktop app or what?  sounds like you might need a background worker or something...   a bit more detail around what you're trying to acheive may help

Comment: Just edited @GPW, sorry about the confusion

Comment: You are not disposing anything. `request`, `response`, `client` - all that implements `IDisposable` and should be disposed (especially `client`, if you are using it like this and not single instance for everything).

Comment: Your timer event will fire on a different thread from the main one, so you almost certainly have a relatively simple blocking issue.  I would either use Synchronous calls (rather than async) inside the timer event - as it doesn't really matter if these block the thread they are on - OR (preferably) re-write it to run a separate thread that manages its own schedule and has a single HttpClient.  This way if one particular request takes a while then it can simply queue the next one until it's done.   I've never found timers are quite good enough for this sort of thing